# How to indicate that a class might implement an interface?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Say I have a class User and an interface Administrator. Some users are administrator and can thus implement the interface. Most aren't, however, so it's false to say that "User implements Administrator".

How can I represent that in a class diagram? Should I use the classic implementation arrow, or is there an existing stereotype for a class that **can** implement an interface?

Comment: Why not have a subclass of User called Administrator? It seems more logical to me than implementing an interface for a class and then restricting the usage for most of the class instances.

Comment: True, but I already have an inheritance tree for User (a user can be a student, a teacher etc., any of which can be a group administrator). How can I represent this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have an `IsAdmin` flag on the `User`?  It sounds like being an admin is a *property* of a user, not an extension to it.

Comment: My idea would then to have other classes that require an Administrator specifically. Like for instance a "Group" class that would have a field "Administrator owner". Of course I could use a flag, turn the "owner" field into an User and add some code to its setter method to check if the flag is true, but it doesn't sounds so right...

Comment: @Bobson that's an ugly solution.  Apart from anything else, it means you can only extend the class in ways envisaged when the User type was first designed.  Not very OO.  Use types for differentiation, not lumps of imperative code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

An Administrator would be a subclass of User, and its primary member attribute would be a User object.

Thus a Student Adminstrator would be an Administrator containing a Student (which is a subclass of User, right?  The Administrator-specific attributes are set in the Adminstrator class, with the User methods passed through from the User object.

Comment: Oooh, really good idea.  Why make Administrator a subclass of User, though?

Comment: Ah yeah, I've heard a similar idea with having an Administrator class containing a User attribute. Then I can use the Administrator everywhere I need it.

Comment: @Bobson the Decorator pattern allows *individual instances* of a class to be enhanced *without* requiring any modification to the design of the original type..  The enhanced object has to be usable wherever the original type can be used.  Otherwise, you have to litter the user object with `isaWhatever` flags, and you can only enhance the object in ways specifically designed in.

Comment: @itsbruce that still doesn't mean that an administrator needs to be a subclass of a user, just that the administrator interface needs to be an extension of the user interface. And even when you don't do that and both interfaces are unrelated (except for the language's root interface interface), you wouldn't need to litter your code with isaWhatever flags. Just request the administrator interface from the user interface reference and have "normal" user interface implementers support a null-pattern for the administrator interface.

Comment: @MarjanVenema  Indeed, the idea behind the decorator pattern would be that the User interface is a generalization (super-type) of the Administrator interface.  The concrete realizations of those interfaces are a separate matter.

Comment: @MarjanVenema with the decorator pattern,  you ask the administrator for the user, not the other way round.

Comment: @itsbruce: My comment was in general and not specific to a decorator. That said, even using a [decorator](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) it should not be necessary to ask an administrator for the user as the decorator class should conform to the interface of the class it decorates, so you should be able to treat every administrator as normal user. And you most certainly would want most of your code to just deal with a user and only check that the user reference it received actually is an administrator when the functionality calls for it.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I made a poor choice of words but so have you.  I would expect an Administrator to either subclass User or to extend (or mix in) a User interface and now you *seem* to be saying the same (I am happy with composition v inheritance, but I was explaining to Bobson the role inheritance plays in Matthew's example).  But before, you said the User interface should be asked for an Administrator interface, which is *not* the same thing and (I think) poor design.  There should be no need for the User interface to know of the admin interface.

Comment: @itsbruce: No you misunderstand. I am not asking the User interface for the admin interface, I am asking the User (interface) __reference__ whether it also happens to support the Admin interface. In Delphi that would be a system call `Supports(UserReference, IAdmin, {out} AdminReference)`, so the User interface doesn't need to know about the Admin interface at all, but the Admin class can implement both, be passed around as a User interface and the system can return the reference to its Admin interface when queried for it.

Answer (score 9):

It makes no sense to say that a class **can** implement an interface.  Either it does or it doesn't, and that's determined as the code is written.  Specific instances (users) can't make that decision for themselves, although they can set an `IsAdministrator` flag instead.

If the `IsAdministrator` flag is insufficient, then (as @superM said) the design you want is **subclassing**.  A `User` has some properties.  Some `User` are actually `Administrator`, which has additional properties.  Therefore `Administrator` inherits from `User`, and should be represented as such.